# Issue with adding a JPanel and add a mouselistener to it

Tags: swing, jpanel, mouselistener

I´m making a simple application in which there are a menu-screen and a game-screen. In the menu-screen there are a go-button and if you click it with the mouse the menu-screen switches to the game-screen, in which there are some simple gameplay.

The main class (it extends JFrame) manages the screen switching and sets up the screens through cardlayout. It sets up a JFrame and a JPanel called cardpanel on it. Cardpanel then adds:

```
cardPanel.add(menu, "menuscreen");
cardPanel.add(game, "gamescreen");
```

menu and game are references to their classes (the classes extends JPanel).

The issue is that when I try to add the JPanel p, which is registered to a mouselistener, in the menu, nothing happens when clicking on it. I tried to add p directly into the main class and it worked since menu is the default visible screen, but when switching to game-room, the users keyboard inputs didn´t work. And when the game-screen was the default one, and p was added directly into main, the inputs did not work. So I really have to add p into the menu-screen, plus, it makes the code look better.

Thankful for help and advices!

Here is the menu class code, in which I have tried to add p: (deleted irrelevant drawing)

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;



public class Menu extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseListener, Commons{

    public static int points = 0;
    public int xMouse;
    public int yMouse;
    private Timer timer;
    private Image image;
    private String backMenu = "backMenu.png";
    private Go go;
    private Logo logo;
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    public Main main;

    public Menu(Main main){
        add(p);
        this.main = main;

                timer = new Timer(5, this);
                timer.start();

                ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(backMenu));
        image = ii.getImage();
        go = new Go();
        logo = new Logo();
        setVisible(true);

        setFocusable(true);

        p.addMouseListener(this);
            p.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if ((e.getX() > go.getX()) && (e.getX() < go.getX()+go.getWidth())){
        if ((e.getY() > go.getY()) && (e.getY() < go.getY()+go.getHeight()))

        {
            main.changeScreen();    
        }
        }

    }
}
```